# How to split a string and breaking it to an array?

Tags: javascript, split

How to split a string and breaking it to an array?

I have an string as shown below

`1234,1243,"555,552,553"`

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to split the string and achieve below array

`['1234','1243','555,552,553']`

Comment: Try to find a library for parsing CSV files, it will have code that processes quotes like this.

Comment: If it is just that string a quick hacky way would be `const arr = JSON.parse(\`[${str}]\`);` But I wouldn't recommend it. Barmar's suggestion to look into CSV parsing is far more robust.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use a regex i thinks, maybe there are better way, but it's need to iterate multiple time.

```
const str = '1234,1243,"555,552,553"';
const regex = /"[^"]+"|[^,]+/g;

const result = str.match(regex).map((item) => item.replace(/"/g, ''));
```

The result is -> `array(3) ['1234', '1243', '555,552,553']`